# TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer even though I assigned it with int(value)

Tags: python, python-3.x, int

When I type in my simple code:

```
times = input("How many times do I have to tell you? ")
times = int(times)

for i in range(times):
    print("Clean your room!")
```

I get the following error message:

```
>>> times = input("How many times do I have to tell you? ")
How many times do I have to tell you? times = int(times)
>>> 
>>> for time in range(times):
...     print("Clean your room!")
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
>>>
```

I am using python 3.8

EDIT:

```
_>>> times = int(input("How many times do I have to tell you? "))
How many times do I have to tell you? 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
>>> for i in range(times):
...     print("Clean your room!")
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'times' is not defined
>>> input("2")
2
''
>>> _
```

I think I am having some problems with my .bashrc and .bash_profile.

Comment: I am also not asked to provide input on my first line - any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Hello as the error tells you:

```
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

first you assing string in line 1.
In line 2 you assing an int.

I checked it again and i can tell both versions work to 100%:

```
times = input("How many times do I have to tell you? ")
times = int(times)

for i in range(times):
    print("Clean your room!")

times = int(input("How many times do I have to tell you? "))

for i in range(times):
    print("Clean your room!")

input("")
```

i added the `input("")` at the end so the console keeps open

if this still wont work we Need to look somewhere else. But I´m sure we will figure this out.

Comment: Thanks for replying!

Unfortunately, this did not resolve the issue for me.

Now, I get an error: times is not defined.

And I am also not asked to provide input on the first line - any idea why?

Also, shouldn't I be able to override the assigned type with a new line? 

I am following an online video and I swear I do exactly the same but I always end up with an error.

Any idea?

Comment: I just added a soulution. you got an error. It should not be int(input(times))

Comment: thanks again. 
Unfortunately, I am still not asked to provide input on my first line. 

I think it has something to do with by .bashrc folder or something ...

Comment: canyou try this: times = int(input("How many times do I have to tell you? ")) and leave out the second line

Comment: can you please check my answer again

Comment: Again, thanks for taking the time to look into this! 

I edited my original post so you can see the error I am getting.