# Messed up my bash_profile and bashrc files - reset to default?

Tags: bash

I think I messed up my .bash_profile and .bashrc file.

Is there any way I can reset them to default?

When I want to access them through the terminal I get: Permission denied.

If I open them using sublime text, my .bashrc is completely empty and my .bash_profile contains the following code:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

alias python=python3

alias sublime="open -a /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app"

source ~/.profile
```

Any idea on what I could add/delete to any of the files?

Python does not run properly anymore since I accidentally played around on those files.

Comment: Access denied usually means you have changed the permissions or ownership of the files. Retry using the root account, probably with `sudo`.

Comment: What the terminal says when you try to run the python command?

Comment: How would I use the sudo command here? - sorry, I am a real beginner!

Comment: in reference to the python error - it just behaves incorrectly when I ask python to carry out a task. I posted one example of an error in a previous post.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59084229/typeerror-str-object-cannot-be-interpreted-as-an-integer-even-though-i-assign]

Comment: I know that apt can reinstall any package with default configurations. But for this case I would try e.g.: https://www.ostechnix.com/restore-bashrc-file-default-settings-ubuntu/ to just recover basrc file from onsystem copy. This seems to me like a duplicate question anyway.

Comment: I agree. Only problem is that when I try to run the first line of the proposed code:
$ cp ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.bak
I already receive an error message -bash: $: command not found
Any idea on how to proceed?

Comment: Perhaps consider creating a new user account and copying the _.bash_profile_ and _.bashrc_ files from the newly created user account to your current user account which has the issue(s). Then remove/delete the newly created temporary user account.

Answer (score 3):

You may find the default .bash_profile and .bashrc files in /etc/skel/

```
[user@server /]$ ls -la /etc/skel
total 28
drwxr-xr-x.   3 root root    78 Jan  3  2019 .
drwxr-xr-x. 131 root root 12288 Nov  7 13:03 ..
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root    18 Oct 30  2018 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root   193 Oct 30  2018 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root   231 Oct 30  2018 .bashrc
```

If it's the case you can get them back:

```
cp /etc/skel/.bash_profile /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
```

Make a backup of your current files before ;)

Just to explain: the content of /etc/skel/ is copied into the home directory of a user when created with adduser.

Comment: Tried the same but still stuck on this :

 `cp: cannot stat '/etc/skel/.bash_profile': No such file or directory `